# More specific template fault logs

Tags: angular

I remember when Angular 2 first came out, any errors made in a template would be written in the console of the browser with the exact line number at fault. However in the most recent Angular versions (and clis), we get a rather unhelpful error message just saying the following:

[image]

Is there a way to bring back the more informative template errors?

Comment: This doesn't look like a template error in and of itself: it looks more like the object you're trying to (legitimately) access is undefined at runtime.

Comment: Is this a production build? Because you can't expect to get any useful output if it is

Comment: @MikeS. this is me just running ng serve and going to localhost. A few years ago I would get more helpful messages than this.